# How to select random object from JSON file in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I've done some searching around and I found some posts on here but my code doesn't want to work.
Basically I'm making a discord bot and I want to select an object from a JSON file at random.

This is my command:

```
const UserData = require('../data/users.js');
const monster = require('../data/monsters.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'battle',
    aliases: ['fight'],
    cooldown: 0,
    description: 'User fights against a monster alone or in group',
    execute(client, message, args) {
        let enemy = monster[Math.floor(Math.random() * monster.length)]

        UserData.findOne({
            userID: message.author.id
        }, (error, userdata) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);

            if (!userdata) {
                return message.reply(`you don't have an account!`);
            } else {
                console.log(enemy);
                return message.channel.send(`${enemy} spawned!`);
            }
        })

    }
}
```

And this is my JSON file:

```
"1" : {
        "name": "Blue Slime",
        "hp": 20,
        "atk": 12,
        "def": 10,
        "spatk": 3,
        "spdef": 12,
        "spd": 100,
        "gold": 10,
        "xp": 50,
        "lvl": 1
    },

    "2": {
        "name": "Red slime",
        "hp": 20,
        "atk": 12,
        "def": 10,
        "spatk": 3,
        "spdef": 12,
        "spd": 100,
        "gold": 10,
        "xp": 50,
        "lvl": 1
    },

    "3": {
        "name": "Green slime",
        "hp": 20,
        "atk": 12,
        "def": 10,
        "spatk": 3,
        "spdef": 12,
        "spd": 100,
        "gold": 10,
        "xp": 50,
        "lvl": 1
    }
}
```

If I want put the objects in the command manually and then randomly select them it works and if instead of "monster.length" I put a number then it also works but I still get undefined if it should be 3.
This way I also always get undefined in console log from monster.length.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The monster.json is an object and not an array, therefore length will be undefined. You can change the monsters.json to an array of objects. No need for an index, just `[objA, objB...]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `monsters.json` file contains an object and objects don't have `length`s. You can however convert it to an array, using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) that returns an array of the given object's own enumerable property values.

Check out the snippet below:

```js
let monsters = {
  1: {
    name: 'Blue Slime',
    hp: 20,
    atk: 12,
    def: 10,
    spatk: 3,
    spdef: 12,
    spd: 100,
    gold: 10,
    xp: 50,
    lvl: 1,
  },

  2: {
    name: 'Red slime',
    hp: 20,
    atk: 12,
    def: 10,
    spatk: 3,
    spdef: 12,
    spd: 100,
    gold: 10,
    xp: 50,
    lvl: 1,
  },

  3: {
    name: 'Green slime',
    hp: 20,
    atk: 12,
    def: 10,
    spatk: 3,
    spdef: 12,
    spd: 100,
    gold: 10,
    xp: 50,
    lvl: 1,
  },
};

function randomObject(obj) {
  let arr = Object.values(obj);
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

let enemy = randomObject(monsters);

console.log(enemy);
```